# firebase realtime DB reading speed is loose

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my work is firebase subscribes to mqtt broker and splits messages received by broker into realtime DB

There is no delay in receiving the mqtt message, but if the node already exists in the DB and if it exists, then the last key value and data write operations take about 1-2 seconds each

here is my code

```
function handleMsg(topic, payload) {
    //send message to start
    const msg_text = payload.toString()
            
    test_promise(msg_text)
    .then(function(snapshot){return test_promise2(snapshot);})
    .then(function(snapshot){return test_promise3(snapshot);})
    .then(function(msg){ console.log(log); log='';})
    .catch(function(msg) { console.log(log); log='';});
}
function test_promise(msg_text){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        msg_split = msg_text.split("::");
        var db_ref = db.ref("backmountain_"+device_id+"_"+time);    
        db_ref.once('value',function(snapshot){
            //strat -> end , 1.4 ~ 2 second
            return resolve(msg_text+"::"+snapshot.exists());
        }).catch(function(err){
            return reject("test_promise reject : "+err);
        });
    });
}
function test_promise2(msg_text){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        var db_ref = db.ref("backmountain_"+device_id+"_"+time);    
        if(chk_exists == "true"){
            //key orderByKey > orderByChild > orderByValue  
            db_ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).once("child_added").then( function(lastkey){
               //strat -> end , 1.4 ~ 2 second
                return resolve(msg_text+"::"+s_id);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                return reject("test_promise2 limitToLast reject : "+err);
            });
        } else if(chk_exists=='false'){
            return resolve(msg_text+"::"+"1");  
        }
    });
}
function test_promise3(msg_text){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        var db_ref = db.ref("backmountain_"+device_id+"_"+time);    
        db_ref.push().set({
            data
        }).catch(function(err){
            return reject("test_promise3 set reject : "+err);
        });
        return resolve("test_promise3 OK : ");
    });
}
```

I have deployed a test function, decomposed each DB task, and tried it one by one, but it happens because the same delay occurred, so it is not delayed by promise

I have mainly worked on the examples, so if you have other good ways or need additional configuration, please answer them.

DB structure is here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB2Td.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=0#update_specific_fields) says following. Why not just save it all as new since that works for you already? You could use a Cloud Function for Firebase to periodically archive/delete old messages.

> For example, a social blogging app might create a post and
>   simultaneously update it to the recent activity feed and the posting
>   user's activity feed using code like this:
>
> ```
> function writeNewPost(uid, username, picture, title, body) {
>   // A post entry.
>   var postData = {
>     author: username,
>     uid: uid,
>     body: body,
>     title: title,
>     starCount: 0,
>     authorPic: picture
>   };
>
>   // Get a key for a new Post.
>   var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;
>
>   // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
>   var updates = {};
>   updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
>   updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;
>
>   return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will refer to this and make it again.